# nsis createting InternetShortcut not displaying icon

Tags: nsis, shortcut

When I try to give custom icon while creating InternetShortcut that particulat icon is not there in created InternetShortcut. Default icon is comming.

Here is code:

```
WriteINIStr "$SMPROGRAMS\Launch_APP.url" "InternetShortcut"  "URL" "http://localhost:9080/myapp/index.php"
WriteINIStr "$SMPROGRAMS\Launch_APP.url" "InternetShortcut"  "IconFile" "$ReadmePath\A.ico"
```

Comment: Hmm ... there is function CreateShortCut (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.3.4) ... why you do not use it?

Comment: @HX_unbanned: you should make it an answer...

Answer (score 1):

`CreateShortcut` uses [IShellLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create shortcuts and is not supposed to be used to create internet shortcuts. The documented interface you are supposed to use to create internet shortcuts is [IUniformResourceLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). NSIS does not have a native instruction for this but it can be called by the system plugin using its COM syntax. To set the icon you would have to QueryInterface for IPropertySetStorage and set [PID_IS_ICONFILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In the end you are just going to end up with the same .ini file which is why a lot of examples (NSIS and other stuff) just write using the .ini API.

You could try adding IconIndex=0 to the .ini but my guess is that the icon path is wrong or icon caching is getting in the way.

Have you tried clearing the icon cache or testing on a different machine?

Comment: Any plans for CreateShortcut with url support in 3.0 branch, Anders?

Comment: HX_unbanned: No, that would mean sniffing for a scheme prefix or something like that...

Comment: Maybe then some kind of link to the COM sample code for *.url creation wuold be good edit for CreateShortCut function documentation? :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for using NSIS.

So - There is function `CreateShortCut` (nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.3.4). it is intended to create any shortcut Windows supports. You should use it. If you find some specific case where it does not work, feel free to mail to Devs in NSIS contact list or create  ticket in their bug-tracker.

Comment: Above code started working when I replaced $SMPROGRAMS with $STARTMENU. Don't know why....

Comment: Well, yeah, that is weird ... but - still - you are creating shortcut  in very very nasty way. Even though it is INI semi-structured file .. :)